# need help getting props to work using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

i'm building this react app and I'm having trouble getting the id, name, & email props to work. i'm trying pull random robot pictures, names and emails from my robots.js file and display it on cards. Any help would be greatly appreciated, here's my code

i keep getting this error
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_robots__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["robots"][0]')

here's the index.js file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import Card from './Card';
    import { robots } from './robots';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

    ReactDOM.render(
                    <div>
                      <Card id={robots[0].id} name={robots[0].name} email={robots[0].email} /> //it's saying this line of code is where the error is coming from
                      <Card id={robots[1].id} name={robots[1].name} email={robots[1].email} />
                      <Card id={robots[2].id} name={robots[2].name} email={robots[2].email} />
                    </div>
      , document.getElementById('root'));

    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

here's robots.js file I only pasted some of the objects in the array just so you get the idea

```
    export const robots = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Leanne Graham',
        username: 'Bret',
        email: 'Sincere@april.biz'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Ervin Howell',
        username: 'Antonette',
        email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Clementine Bauch',
        username: 'Samantha',
        email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net'
      },
    ];
```

here's the Card.js file

```
    import React from 'react';
    import 'tachyons';

    const Card = ({name, email, id}) =>{
      return(
        <div className="tc bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow bw2 shadow-5">
          <img alt='robots' src={'https://robohash.org/${id}?200x200'} />
          <div>
            <h2>{name}</h2>
            <p>{email}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default Card;
```

Comment: Would be nice if you share your error messages as well

Comment: it's working for me too.

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_robots__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["robots"][0]')

Comment: that's the error I'm getting

Comment: you should use map method   ReactDOM.render()

Comment: I'll try that. maybe atom is messing with me I'll try downloading sublime and see if it works in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is I provide a working example

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-xr4sf

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Card from './Card';
import { robots } from './robots';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        {robots.map(robot => <Card  key={robot.id} id={robot.id} name={robot.name} email={robot.email} />)}
    </div>
, document.getElementById('root'));

    serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_robots__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["robots"].map')

Comment: Not sure why that is. Everything seems to work when reproducing it: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stackoverflow-57989977-umt14)

Comment: I deleted and re dowloaded all the react files and now everything including my original code is working

Answer (score 1):

**There you should use map method to run through you object**

```
import React from 'react';
        import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
        import './index.css';
        import Card from './Card';
        import { robots } from './robots';
        import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

        ReactDOM.render( <div>
           {robots.map(obj => <Card id={obj.id} name={obj.name} email={obj.email} />)}
                        </div>, document.getElementById('root'));

        serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleting and re downloading all the react files and now everything including my original code is working